# PHP | Regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a problem with the capture in regular expressions

```
$f = function($doc)
{

 $data = [];

 preg_match_all("/[\s]*[\/\*\s]*(.+)[\/\*\s]*/i", $doc, $matches);

 var_dump($matches);

};


$f("
    /**
     * test
     *
     * @param string \$comment
     *
     * @return array
     */

     ");
```

dump (everything is as it should be):

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "@param string $comment"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "@return array"
  }
```

if I do this

```
$f("/** @var array ___TEST___ */");
```

dump:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "@var array ___TEST___ */"
  }
```

why are captured by the last two (*/) characters?

Comment: What is expected? I think you are miss using character character classes here. You want `@var array ___TEST___ ` in capture group 1? The title of this question also is not a good one, you should provide a title that details what the question is asking.

Comment: Maybe [this will do](https://regex101.com/r/Uem2BC/1)?

Comment: Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel with regex, you might want to take a look at existing DocBlock Parsers like [phpDocumentor's ReflectionDocBlock](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock)

Comment: somehow I feel like the dumps don't match the regex exactly, but `matches[1]`. However, since `.*` matches literally everything, the following `*/` can be matched as well. the following `[whatever]*` doesn't need to occur, so this match is quite alright.

Answer (score 0):

So lets break it down from here `[\/\*\s]*`

Your square brackets mean any single character from within the brackets.

`\` is an escape character, so `\/` means match `/`

Likewise `\*` means match `*`

Then `\s` means match any whitespace character.

the `*` after your square brackets makes it greedy, so it can match an unlimited amount of times.

Your string ends with a whitespace character (match), then a * (match), then a / (match)

and that's why it matches